# Hierarchy/dependancies between xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a page, for which I identified 2 elements I want to get, with their xpath:

```
temp1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/./div/div[1]/div[1]")
temp2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]")

for elm1 in temp1:
    print(elm1.text)
    print("---")
    for elm2 in temp2:
        print(elm2.text)   <--   but I only want the ones "below" the elm1 element
    print("---------")
```

How do I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd99i.png)

Comment: temp2 is not empty at all : it gives a list of the elements I want, except that it's not logically linked to the other ones

Comment: You need to share the html. Also using such xpath is not recommended. Xpath should be more readable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate elements related to another element you need to use it when locating those elements inside the loop

```
temp1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/./div/div[1]/div[1]")
for elm1 in temp1:
    print(elm1.text)
    print("---")

    temp2 = elm1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]")
    for elm2 in temp2:
        print(elm2.text)

    print("---------")
```

Comment: sorry but i don't understand (how to do that)

Comment: @jeremoquai just take the code from my answer. `temp2 = elm1.find_elements_by_xpath` is the line where it's performed.

Comment: doesn't work : i just reexecuted my code, and it gives the 2 lists with items in each, but when executing yours i unfortunately have only the items of the first list and no items from the second

Comment: the xpath is wrong. The xpath should be relative to elm1

Comment: @jeremoquai the xpath is taken from your question, if you post the html I can have a look.

Comment: as an example this page : https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/match/prelive/19323802

Comment: the first list gives the types of bet, the second the various possibilities

Comment: @jeremoquai I can't open this link from where I am, add the html to the question.

Comment: but at the current time there is no link between the 2, although one exists, and i need to have it

Comment: replace temp2 line as: temp2 = elm1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ancestor::div[3]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]"). Not sure if it will work

Comment: @jeremoquai just the relevant part, from `id='app-inner'` to the elements you want.

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 62742 (I do my best)

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: sorry i really try to insert some code but it keeps on saying me "too many code"

Comment: wouldn't an "and" in the find_element_by_xpath be the solution (although i'm really not familiar with the syntax) ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were close. The code block within the `for()` loop:

```
for elm1 in temp1:
    # lines of code
    # more lines of code
```

Would iterate for the elements with in the list `temp1` only.

Where as to iterate over the elements with in the list `temp2` you have to unindent the line of code. So effectively, your line of code will be:

```
temp1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/./div/div[1]/div[1]")
temp2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]")

for elm1 in temp1:
    print(elm1.text)
    print("---")
for elm2 in temp2:
    print(elm2.text)
    print("---------")
```

---

Alternatively, you can also:

```
for elm1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/./div/div[1]/div[1]"):
    print(elm1.text)
    print("---")
for elm2 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='app-inner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]"):
    print(elm2.text)
    print("---------")
```

Comment: gives the same results : two lists one after the other with no link between the 2 ! as an example (i post a screenshot) I need the names of the scorers ONLY after the type of bet "Scorers"

Comment: sorry i really try to insert some code but it keeps on saying me "too many code"

Comment: wouldn't an "and" in the find_element_by_xpath be the solution (although i'm really not familiar with the syntax) ?

Comment: Do you want to store the elements selected with both the criteria in the same list?

Comment: i want to have "BUTEUR AU COURS DU MATCH : Mohamed Salah", "BUTEUR AU COURS DU MATCH : Sadio Mane", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are using parent element to find only the text inside the parent.

```
temp1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='appinner']/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/./div/div[1]/div[1]")
for elm1 in temp1:
    print(elm1.text)
    print("---")

    #using elm1 and then navigating within using relative xpath
    ele2 = elm1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//../../../div[*]/div/div[2]/div/div[*]/div/div[1]")

    for elm2 in temp2:
        print(elm2.text)   

    print("---------")
```